# Azure ports required?

Tags: azure

I have searched the Azure docs, various community forums and google but I have not found a succinct statement of what ports need to be opened on a company firewall to allow all components of Azure (blob, sql, compute, bus, publish) to function.

For example from what I have read so far, it appears that 1433 is required for SQL Azure, 9354 for Service Bus, 443 for Connect.  What else is required?  I would like to go to the IT department once with a complete list.

Best Wishes,
Todd

Comment: I would start with itemizing the features of Windows Azure you wish to utilize. You don't want to open all of the ports, because any port that you don't end up using is a possible attack vector into your infrastructure.

Comment: Are you looking to open outgoing ports or incoming ports?  For most of the stuff, you do not need to open any incoming ports.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to open 9354 for service bus, since the service bus will try to connect over tcp (9354), if failed it will use http (80), which I believe your IT will not block 80 and 443. But if you need RDC, I guess you need open 3389.

Answer (score 6):

http://web.archive.org/web/20160209030006/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/02/07/azure-ports.aspx

I attempted to indicate some of them. I think it is pretty thorough.

Comment: Is it worth including the ports in your answer? MSDN blogs have a habit of being unreliable stores of information long term.

Comment: Definitely copy the relevant content here (had a hard time loading that linked-page from work).

Comment: @Doug and GoneCoding were right. The link is now no longer valid..